# Creating a Table of Powers with C++

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, nested-loops, exponent

I'm working on a project to print out a table of exponential numbers using nested for-loops. Users specify the number of rows to print and the number of powers.  For example, if the users specifies 2 rows and 3 powers, the program should print 1,1,1 and 2,4,9 (2^1,2,3 etc).  I should note this is for class and we aren't allowed to use cmath, otherwise I would use pow().  I can't seem to figure out the correct function in a nested for loop that can change both values of the base and the exponent.  Here's what I have so far.  Thanks for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int r, p, a;
    cout << "The program prints a table of exponential powers.\nEnter the number of rows to print: ";
    cin >> r;
    cout << "Enter the number of powers to print: " ;
    cin >> p;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= r; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << i;       
        for (int q = 1; q <= i; q++)
        {
            a = (q * q); //This only works for static numbers...
            cout << setw(8) << a;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your expected pattern, `1 1 1` in the first line and `2 4 9` in the second line does not make sense. Did you mean `2 4 8` in the second line? `2^1 2^2 2^3`??

Comment: Try something simpler: a program that prints *one* line powers, of variable length. Hint: don't calculate each power in isolation.

Comment: [Working code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57e7a0eaf621bb08).

Comment: @RSahu, yes you are correct; I was typing hastily and made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= r; i++)
{
    cout << setw(2) << i;
    int a = 1;
    for (int q = 1; q <= r; q++)
    {
        a = (a * i);
        cout << setw(8) << a;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Several things to note. First, you can compute the powers by maintaining the variable a and multiplying it by i for each power. Also, I think you want the upper bound on your second loop to be r and not i.

Answer (score 0):

You need couple to change the way accumulate the values of raising a number to a power.

Also, you are using the wrong variable to end the loop in the inner for-loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int r, p, a;
   cout << "The program prints a table of exponential powers.\nEnter the number of rows to print: ";
   cin >> r;
   cout << "Enter the number of powers to print: " ;
   cin >> p;
   cout << endl;

   for (int i = 1 ; i <= r; i++)
   {
      cout << setw(2) << i;       
      a = 1;   // Start with 1
      for (int q = 1; q <= p; q++) // That needs to <= p, not <= i
      {
         a *= i; // Multiply it by i get the value of i^q
         cout << setw(8) << a;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```